# How to create typeorm entity for postgresql MATERIALIZED VIEW

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm, materialized-views

I have an existing **MATERIALIZED VIEW** in my postgresql database. I am trying to create typeorm entity for that. Can anyone tell me how to do that. I already went through [typeorm View Entities docs](https://typeorm.io/#/view-entities) but it's not useful as I expected.

Answer (score 6):

The support was added in this [PR](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/3996), and as mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62513489/9157407) it was resolved by using `{ materialized:true }` along with `ViewEntity`, it may be a good idea to provide a clear example in the future.

Answer (score 2):

as of currently it is not possible to do so

here are issues thread

https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/4317

https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/3996